# Javat Script filter array and Display item

Tags: javascript, array-filter

How would I log a single item in filtered array?

```
let data= [ { id: 1, name: 'Mike', city: 'philps', state:'New York'}, { id: 2, name: 'Steve', city: 'Square', state: 'Chicago'}, { id: 3, name: 'Jhon', city: 'market', state: 'New York'}, { id: 4, name: 'philps', city: 'booket', state: 'Texas'}, { id: 5, name: 'smith', city: 'brookfield', state: 'Florida'}, { id: 6, name: 'Broom', city: 'old street', state: 'Florida'}, ]

data = data.filter((item) => item.state == 'New York').map(({id, name, city}) => ({id, name, city}));
console.log(data.name);//--->>> get an item-----------
```

Comment: There is no question provided

Comment: so what do you want

Comment: Looks like you should read about arrays, methods of arrays, and how to get items from array

Comment: sorry I edited, not too sure how to use stack yet

Comment: Should there be only one item, that matches your filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

console.log(data.length && data[0] .name). Map is useless in your code

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to use the first item, you could use .find() like this:

```
data = data.find((item) => item.state == 'New York'); console.log(data.name);
```

If you want to display all items, that match your filter you could use foreach:

```
data = data.filter((item) => item.state == 'New York').forEach(d=> console.log(d.name));
```

The question is: What do you really want?